# ValueError: Layer 'lstm_cell_2' expected 3 variables, but received 0 variables during loading

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

i am using Keras to save my Bi-Lstm model on Google Colab using the following code

```
with open('BiLstm_model.pkl', 'wb') as writer:
    pickle.dump(lstm_model, writer)
```

Now, when i am loading this model using the code in my local pc, it is showing the error shown in the image.

```
lstm_model = pickle.load(open('BiLstm_model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOXaX.png)

Whenever I load the model in Google colab, it is working, but when I load it in my local PC it gives me the error. I have already tried using different formats and libraries to save the model and to load it. Also I have already installed the same version of packages as specified and used in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to try using hdf5 to save and load your model. Here is the code snippet below

```
lstm_model.save('BiLstm_model.h5')
```

and load this using

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
lstm_model = load_model('./models/BiLstm_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be you saved the model in a different TensorFlow version from the version you are using on your local machine.

To fix this try installing the same TensorFlow version Google Collab used when saving the model as a .keras file onto your local machine.

I had a similar issue to this and using the correct TensorFlow version solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The trick was checking whether the tensorflow version on my local machine was the same as the version Google Colab ran while saving the model.

```
tf. __version__
```

Next, I had to reload my model in Google colab (while running the older version of Tensorflow on which I saved my model)

```
!pip install tensorflow==*the version you need*
```

Then you should resave and download your model but as a .h5 file type instead of .keras

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/yourmodel.keras')
model.save("yourmodel.h5") #
!ls
from google.colab import files
files.download('yourmodel.h5')
```

Now you can load your model on your local machine.
(I loaded my model in Colab via Google Drive but you can do this on any way you want)